# OS X 10.9.2 and Eclipse 4.2.2: "Symbol 'std' could not be resolved" in Hello World program

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, osx-mavericks

I am using Eclipse v 4.2.2 on OS X 10.9.2 with C/C++ Development Tools Version 8.1.2.201302132326.

Anyone know how to use the Eclipse  C++ plugin on a Mac?  I keep getting `Symbol 'std' could not be resolved.`  I have searched through many pages on this and none of the answers have worked for me.

I have Xcode installed, as well as Xcode command line tools.  I tried setting MacOSX GCC as well as XL C/C++ Toolchain as default toolchain.

Also I noticed under C/C++ Build > XL C/C++ Compiler, I have a warning that says `Compiler path does not exist on the local machine.`  I tried setting the path to /usr/bin/gcc which is where my compiler is per `which gcc` terminal command.  Restarted Eclipse.  No dice.

Code in my cpp file:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if you try to use clang?  GCC has been deprecated in OS X for awhile now.  Their default compiler is LLVM.

Comment: I would suggest you to use Xcode for C++ development unless there are some other reasons for you to use Eclipse.